# Android GeoLocation FireStore: A way to stop google service from getting geopoints of a user once user turns off the location sharing option

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, google-cloud-firestore, android-service

I am trying to build a tracking application where I get users GeoPoints with users permission and then upload that on Firestore database. After that I use the Geopoints to add markers on map which helps to locate a particular user on google map. However, I am planning to add an option to hide location for the user which when chosen by the user, the location of that particular user won't be visible on the map.I am using google service to constantly update the location of a user. Can someone please shed a little light on it,how I can stop getting the location of a user and remove the marker from the google maps for that particular user? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of, is to add under each user object a new property of type `Boolean` named `locationSharing` with the default value of `true`. Once the user decides to go private, just change the value of this new property to `false`. Now, attach a snapshot listener on the user document to see the changes of `locationSharing` property in real time. If the value of `locationSharing` property turns into `false`, then just stop updating the location of the user on Google Maps. That's it.

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you so much for the help. Yes it worked. P.S. your YouTube channel is very helpful, thanks a lot for the tutorials :)